# Googe Big-Query - cannot union 3 tables - error comes up "cannot run query"

Tags: google-bigquery

In google big query im trying to union 4-5 tables together.

Im using union query.
Below query does not work - "cannot run query" error comes up.

```
(SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw1`)
union all
(SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw2`)
union all
(SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw3`)
```

This query works:

```
(SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw1`)
union all
(SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw2`)
```

also this query works:

```
SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw1` 
union all
SELECT * FROM `mimetic-core-279214.Smart.kw3`
```

What could be the issue. 
Can someone please help.

Comment: any more details to share? what is **exact** error message?

Comment: what error did you get? did you try to use wildcard instead of union all in such scenarios? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Comment: Please, share the complete error